# How do I earn coins?

Tags: disney-emoji-blitz

I have various missions where I need to earn coins, and I know I get coins while I am playing, but I haven't figured out how.

What events in the game give you coins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [guide](https://recombu.com/mobile/article/disney-emoji-blitz-tips-tricks-hacks-cheats-guide-unlock-all-emoji), there are several events that gives you coins in-game:

1. Completing a game - number of coins depends on your score and which Hero Emoji you used.
2. Finishing missions and levelling up - Reward Chests give coins as well
3. Tapping on the 'Free Prize' in the Emoji Store every 8 hours often gives you coins or gems.
4. Gems can also be swapped for coins

But other than that, as the system seems very similar to TsumTsum, the fastest way is probably to [grind it out through playing many games](http://www.gamezebo.com/2016/07/20/disney-emoji-blitz-tips-cheats-strategies/).